# Using an optocoupler to drive a pulse counter

Tags: opto-isolator

I am trying to design a circuit to measure the RPM of a small internal combustion engine.

The ignition on the engine is a simple magneto style ignition. These ignitions are switched off by grounding a wire. When not grounded, the wire carries a signal that pulses once per revolution from 0V to up to 270V. The pulse length is typically 5 micro seconds.

Because the engine drives a remote controlled vehicle, it is important to isolate the ignition from the rest of the electronics, to reduce RF noise. Thus, I was thinking about using an optocoupler to take the pulse as input, with a suitable resistor in series to limit the current. On the output side, I am thinking about connecting the source to a pull-down resistor, and the drain to +Vcc of the Arduino.

The idea is to turn the input pulse (the yellow curve in the below image) into a square wave, and that is why I am thinking about a MOSFET-based optocoupler. The source would be connected to an input pin on the Arduino, programmed to work as a pulse counter (I have that part already done).  The square wave does not have to have the same width of the pulse. In fact, I would like the square wave to overlap the portion of the pulse above 50V.

So my question is: What is the best optocoupler to use, and what is the best way to apply the 50V threshold?

[image: The yellow pulse is the one that is fed to the optocoupler. Note that here it is inverted]

*Figure 1: The yellow pulse is the one that is fed to the optocoupler. Note that here it is inverted*

Comment: Are you sure that this signal has enough current capacity to drive an optocoupler? Put a 100k resistor to ground and measure again.

Comment: You could use a small “pulse” transformer to step down the voltage and impedance with isolation then characterize the pulse after that for converting a logic level with a sufficiently high inductance for the 80kHz band region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the signal is very weak and can't drive much of a load. If it can drive 100k, something like this should work. I plain NPN optocoupler should work, I don't see an advantage here to a MOSFET Opto.

If the 50 V threshold is important, this won't be accurate. If you are only building a few, you could hand-tune it. If a 50 V threshold is important, you should consider a pulse transformer like Tony recommended.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA3VHM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I ran the engine with a 47k resistor to ground. The scope gave essentially the same reading, so I am confident that it can drive the opto. As far as -50V threshold, the rest of the waveform is between +10V and -10V, so it does not have to be very precise. I will give it a try, but for now I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: @user3646557 - if any noise is causing extra pulses, you could reduce the sensitivity by placing a zener in series with R1. 10 or 20V will help.

Comment: I actually built the circuit and it worked. One question, though, what is the purpose of the 22pF capacitor in parallel to the LED in the optocoupler?

Comment: R1 and C1 form a filter to reduce false triggering. For pulses it is easier to think of the time constant of the filter. This time constant is 2.2 uS (100k * 22pF). So, in rough terms, a 5 uS pulse will mostly get through, and 2 uS and less will be attenuated.